# iOS map overlay not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, overlay, mapkit

I'm creating an application that sends a call request for any available user across the US and updates the call sender on the progress via map overlays and a progress bar in the meantime. For some reason, the map and progress bar do not update to the final step, no matter what tricks I try with Grand Central Dispatch, CATransaction, etc. Note that I am using Parse for the backend and completing operations in a block after getting the object.

```
    dispatch_queue_t main_queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    PFQuery *repQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
    [repQuery getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[_currentCallObject objectForKey:@"Rep"] block:^(PFObject *repUser, NSError *error) {
        PFGeoPoint *repLocation = [repUser objectForKey:@"location"];
        dispatch_async(main_queue, ^{
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[2];
            coordinates[0] = _repMapView.userLocation.coordinate;
            coordinates[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(repLocation.latitude, repLocation.longitude);
            MKPolyline *route = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:2];
            MKCircle *circle1 = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:coordinates[0] radius:40000];
            MKCircle *circle2 = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:coordinates[1] radius:40000];
            [_repMapView addOverlay:circle1];
            [_repMapView addOverlay:circle2];
            [_repMapView addOverlay:route];
            [_repMapView setNeedsDisplay];
            [_callProgressView setProgressToStep:4];
            [CATransaction flush];
        });
    }];
```

The progress view is contained in a separate .m file, but the overlays are drawn in the same .m file as such:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    // MKCircle and MKPolyline handled here
}
```

I also put all the following in the header file:
    MKMapViewDelegate, MKAnnotation, MKOverlay
Also, _repMapView.delegate = self; was set in the initial drawing of the map view.

Am I missing something obvious here that is causing the UI to fail to update in real time?

Thanks.

Comment: Whenever I've had this problem, it always turned out to be something infuriatingly simple like a bad `IBOutlet` or `delegate`. You don't need `setNeedsDisplay`. You don't need `CATransaction`. Can you do some add'l diagnostics (e.g. logged `_repMapView`'s `overlays` array when you're all done to make sure stuff got added as you thought; NSLog/breakpoint in `viewForOverlay` to see if that's even getting called; look at the actual latitude/longitude values). You need to narrow down where it's going awry. Short of some unnecessary calls, I see nothing wrong with the your `MKMapView`-related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I had that code within a block that was not being entered because a condition I assumed true was not. The verification that it wasn't the map code helped me pin down that very basic unrelated problem. Thanks.